# When starting , "couldn't get size : 0x800000000000000e;couldn't getUEFI db list "

Tags: boot, startup, busybox

I installed Ubuntu via a mobile SSD in my notebook computer.
I'm learning Tensorflow in ubuntu, a total novice.

```
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

[image]